# how to make a asp.net page without any payload just a string in the sourcecode?

Tags: asp.net

normaly a asp.net page looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Foo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Foos" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="my text"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and then i get displayed "my text".

the problem is, now i need to make a page and just display the "my text" without the html stuff in the background. so when i look in the sourcecode it should just be `my text`

of course i need the asp.net in the background to change the label text.

is this possible?

Comment: i dont understand wat do u want to do ??? do u want to render something like control ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete everything except the page tag, and on Page_Load write my text in the response

In the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Foo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Foos" %>
```

In the .cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write("My text")
}
```

Or you can add a literal to the page (set it's value in the code behind) and remove the html stuff like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Foo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Foos" %>
<asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server" />
```